# Regex find href after certain word

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<a href="">ABCD</a>
<a href="text1">ABCD</a>
<a href="text2">ABCD</a>
```

I need js regex to find first href after "ABCD", "text1" not "text2".

Comment: I think this regex should work: `^.*?ABCD.*?href="(.*?)".*$`

Comment: Not realy https://regex101.com/r/tbliia/1

Comment: No, Regex101 is applying that regex to each separate line.  In your JS code, the regex should treat newline as any other character in the string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the pattern in your comment works when the line breaks are replaced with \r\n (as advised) so make this an answer!

Comment: Even if i write it as single line `<a href="">ABCD</a><a href="text1">ABCD</a><a href="text2">ABCD</a>` it selects whole string.

Comment: @ConstantineBateruk then you'll need to extract the first match group at `$1`

Comment: @ConstantineBateruk Stop using Regex101 when your actual problem is JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the suggestion of @G0dsquad I have posted a formal answer.  The regex pattern I used below is:

```
^.*?ABCD.*?href="(.*?)".*$
```

```js
var input = "<a href=\"\">ABCD</a><a href=\"text1\">ABCD</a><a href=\"text2\">ABCD</a>";
var regex = /^.*?ABCD.*?href="(.*?)".*$/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Note that I stripped away the line breaks in the input to cram everything into a single line.  But adding newline characters should not change the behavior of the regex.  Also note that Regex101, while a very useful tool, appears to apply the regex to each individual line, which will not be your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You are not very specific but this

```
>\w+<[^h]*href="([^"]*)"
```

should be close to what you are looking for.

Note: You want to get not the whole match but the first capture group.

[Live demo](http://regexr.com/3fio3) (click Tools -> List to check the groups)

Comment: If you only want the word ABCD then replace w+ with it